# I'm trying to get the X and Y values of the Text-Shadow on an element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the CSS giving this element a text shadow:

```
h2 {
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:30%;
    text-shadow: 100px 100px 10px black;
}
```

and I'm running jQuery to `console.log()` the `textShadow` value:

```
var shadow = $('div').css('textShadow');
console.log(shadow);
```

The result is: `rgb(0, 0, 0) 100px 100px 10px`.

How can I parse this string to get the X and the Y values separately?

Comment: So, your question is simpler. How can I get `100` and `100` from `rgb(0, 0, 0) 100px 100px 10px`?

Comment: You can use shadow.split(" "); to split your string using whitespace.

Comment: yeah i realize i can slice it up, but is it possible to select the specific values?

Comment: When you have your string sliced you can get all your values with a for loop.

Comment: For loop?! just access the array like in my answer...

Comment: I ment in general. He can obtain all values using a for loop. Your answer is precisely what he needs. Using direct indexes on small objects like this is trivial exactly.

Comment: This is what i was playing with, thanks again for the help

https://jsfiddle.net/barrard/9jf755kh/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer this method:

```
var shadow = $("div").css("text-shadow").split(" ");
var x = shadow[1];
var y = shadow[2];
```

I prefer using split() and join() over regex since it's less error prone and easier to understand for most people ^^

As mentioned in the comments it might have more spaces because of a rgb value :/
solution:

```
var shadow = $("div").css("text-shadow").split(" ");
var count = 0;
var xy = [];
for(var x = 0; x < shadow.length; x++) {
    if(shadow[x].indexOf("px") >= 0 && count < 2) { //position value otherwise skip
        xy.push(shadow[x]);
        count++;
    }
}
var x = xy[0];
var y = xy[1];
```

edit: replaced split() with split(" "), small mistake :P

Comment: If you add `" "` in `split()` and use `3` and `4` instead of `1` and `2`, it will work.

Comment: i just did it with splice, but i like this split method, more easy.  The RegEx is over my head.  Thank yo all for the creative answers!

Comment: Yes, you musn't ignore those spaces. They weren't removed.

Comment: Added for loop that checks if the array values generated by split are position or color values.

Answer (score 1):

Use following regex to match `x` and `y` values:

```
var match = $('div').css('textShadow').match(/rgb\(\d+, \d+, \d+\) ([^ ]+) ([^ ]+)/);
var x = match[1], y = match[2];
```

I assume that the div always has `text-shadow` property, because otherwise `.match()` would return `null`.